# How to call a class when a class within a Static

Tags: c#, static

Hello friends I face this question in one Interview in statics(Myclass). I have two clases one is `M1` and `M2`.

How can I call m2 in m1 and m1 in m2? and also How to create an Instance of an static?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          //in this Portion How can I call all member if MyClass
        }


     public static class Myclass
                {
                    public static class  M1
                    {
                     //Here How can I call m2
                    }
                    public class m2
                    {
                    //Here How can I call m1
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For static class M1, you need to call using class name.
 For non static class M2, you need to create instance.
 you can call methods/properties, and not classes.

```
public static class Myclass
    {
       public static void Main(String[] args)
       {
          // call something on  m2
          var m2 = new Myclass.m2();
          m2.A2(); // call m2.A2 method

          // call something on m1
          Myclass.m1.A1();
        }
        public static class M1
        {
            //Here How can I call m2
            public static void A1()
            {
                var m2 = new Myclass.m2(); // create m2instance
                m2.A2(); // call m2
            }
        }
        public class m2
        {
            //Here How can I call m1
            public void A2()
            {
                Myclass.M1.A1(); // called M1.A1
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello @Tilak if i wana to call   static void Main(string[] args)
        {
         //Here how can i call 
        }

Comment: Program.Main(args); // where args -> String array. Usually main method is called at program startup by CLR. You do not need to call it.

Comment: Thank u Soo much mr @Tilak

Answer (score 0):

You can not call a class, and as it is static you can not Generate new class of that type but you can call methods and functions of it easily like this:

```
public static class Myclass
            {
                public static class  M1
                {
                 public static class Method2(){
                  }
                  new m2().AMethod();
                }
                public class m2
                {
                //Here How can I call m1
                 public static void AMethod(){  
                     //method 
                }
             }
          }
```

And for main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          new MyClass.m2().AMethod();
          MyClass.M1.Method2();
        }
```

Comment: Thank u soo much Mr.Askan

Comment: How can I Contact u